# Not getting the proper Log in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was just testing stuff because I started using VSCode , then I realised something that *I think* is wrong. whenever I just log something that is calculated using a method, It logs function:*method name*.
Any suggestions ?

example :

```
class square {
    constructor(width, height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    get area() {
        return this.calculateArea
    }

    calculateArea() {
        this.width * this.height
    }
}

const square1 = new square(5, 8);
console.error(square1.area);
```

this logs [Function: calculateArea].

Comment: change `return this.calculateArea` to `return this.calculateArea()`

Answer (score 3):

You return the function, not the result.

Should be `return this.calculateArea()`